# Regex is working. But seriously dont know, what is wrong in some parts

Tags: python, regex

Hi I am having a problem with the regex in the following link.

https://regex101.com/r/wU4xK1/1

It matches almost all patterns. But when it encounter some characters or newline I am struggling.

My regex is :

```
 (\b(?:(jan|january|feb|february|mar|march|apr|april|may|jun|june|jul|july|aug|august|set|sep|september|oct|october|nov|november|dec|december)[/\.\s',’-]{0,4}\d{2,4}|(jan|january|feb|february|mar|march|apr|april|may|jun|june|jul|july|aug|august|set|sep|september|oct|october|nov|november|dec|december))[/\r-–––,]{0,4}[a-zA-Z]{3,8}[/\.\s',’-]{0,2}[\s]{0,4}\d{2,4})
```

My text is:

```
July 2005 – December - 2006 

(Nov '12 - Feb 12)

(Nov 12 - Feb 12       )

july 2005 – Dec 2012 ## Note here. If i press enter after Dec 2012 I will    get a match. Dont know why ?
```

Comment: post the regex here along with the test string.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Moreover it gives me a match on single word combo like "February 2012". But I am trying to match a pattern like a start date to end date

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj - I am on travel. If you reply anything i will follow up on you.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - (Nov '12 - Feb 12)

(Nov 12 - Feb 12       ) These things have to match without brackets. When i include a \S it matches for the first thing. Not for the later one.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Any possible match of start date to end date. In any format. like jan '12 - jan 2012 , jan 2012 - jan. 2012 , jan-12 jan-14, jan 2013 - jan 14, . Numerical forms like 12/2014 - 12/2015 I am doing seperate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just turn all the capturing group to non-capturing group and then include the whole pattern inside a single capturing group.

```
((?:\b(?:(?:jan|january|feb|february|mar|march|apr|april|may|jun|june|jul|july|aug|august|set|sep|september|oct|october|nov|november|dec|december)[/\.\s',’-]{0,4}\d{2,4}|(jan|january|feb|february|mar|march|apr|april|may|jun|june|jul|july|aug|august|set|sep|september|oct|october|nov|november|dec|december))[/\r-–––,]{0,4}[a-zA-Z]{3,8}[/\.\s',’-]{0,2}[\s]{0,4}\d{2,4}))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wU4xK1/2)

```
>>> s = '''July 2005 – December - 2006 

(Nov '12 - Feb 12)

(Nov 12 - Feb 12       )

july 2005 – Dec 2012 ## Note here. If i press enter after Dec 2012 I will    get a match. Dont know why ?'''
>>> re.findall(r"(?mi)((?:\b(?:(?:jan|january|feb|february|mar|march|apr|april|may|jun|june|jul|july|aug|august|set|sep|september|oct|october|nov|november|dec|december)[/\.\s',’-]{0,4}\d{2,4}|(jan|january|feb|february|mar|march|apr|april|may|jun|june|jul|july|aug|august|set|sep|september|oct|october|nov|november|dec|december))[/\r-–––,]{0,4}[a-zA-Z]{3,8}[/\.\s',’-]{0,2}[\s]{0,4}\d{2,4}))", s)
[('July 2005 – December - 2006', ''), ("Nov '12 - Feb 12", ''), ('Nov 12 - Feb 12', ''), ('july 2005 – Dec 2012', '')]
>>> m = re.findall(r"(?mi)((?:\b(?:(?:jan|january|feb|february|mar|march|apr|april|may|jun|june|jul|july|aug|august|set|sep|september|oct|october|nov|november|dec|december)[/\.\s',’-]{0,4}\d{2,4}|(jan|january|feb|february|mar|march|apr|april|may|jun|june|jul|july|aug|august|set|sep|september|oct|october|nov|november|dec|december))[/\r-–––,]{0,4}[a-zA-Z]{3,8}[/\.\s',’-]{0,2}[\s]{0,4}\d{2,4}))", s)
>>> [(x) for x,y in m]
['July 2005 – December - 2006', "Nov '12 - Feb 12", 'Nov 12 - Feb 12', 'july 2005 – Dec 2012']
```

`(?mi)` here we combined multiline and case-insensitive modifier.

Comment: Hey. How come this "February 2012" matches here. As per my knowledge, we are doing a match of patterns that must "start" and "end". I checked it, but couldn't find the mistake.      https://regex101.com/r/wU4xK1/9

Comment: Hi. It still matching "February 2012" man. I dont know whats really happening.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex indeed works, but you have to **delete the blank line** at the end of your Regular expression.
See 
https://regex101.com/r/wU4xK1/3

Answer (score 0):

Apart from correct Aaron's remark (after removing that line break, the matches are displayed), I'd also like to mention that \s matches any white space character in **[\r\n\t\f ]** class, so you could avoid capturing line breaks by limiting the group to **[\t\f ]**.